# Sage automatically/unnecessarily rounds ratio of two integers inside double loop.

Tags: sagemath

I am not very familiar with Sage so maybe it is obvious.

Input to Sage:

```
i=3;
j=2;
print(i/j);
for i in range(3,4):
      for j in range(2,3):
            print(i/j);
```

Output from Sage:

```
3/2
1
```

> First output is as expected $3/2$, but why the second output is not
>   also $3/2$ but it is rounded to $1$?

I want to loop over rationals - over numerators and over denominators, but the rounding makes it impossible.

**EDIT:**
Solved using `srange` instead of `range`.

Input to Sage:

```
i=3;
j=2;
print(i/j);
for i in srange(3,4):
      for j in srange(2,3):
            print(i/j);
```

Output from Sage:

```
3/2
3/2
```

Comment: Looks like a bug to me, but I could be wrong. That is, incidentally, valid Python code as well, which yields 1 and 1. You can force floating-point if you throw in something like `print(i*1.0/j)`. One guess is that the output of the `range` function is not the same type, precisely, as the result of `i=3;`.

Comment: @Adrian Keister: I solved the problem - see edit of my question. And, yes, it was problem with the type of variables $i$ and $j$ inside and outside of the loops.

Comment: To be explicit, `range` gives Python `int`s which divide to zero in Python 2; in Py3 they will give different output so watch out in the future!

Comment: By the way, you don't need semicolons for Sage/Python.  Glad you figured it out on your own, nice work!